# PHP 404 and 406 error while using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm going to be mad with this problem. It's really weird that how I can explain.
I was doing jquery GET ajax request to a php file to submit comment in my website. The weird thing is I get the following error for some comments(not all) in the response:

> ### Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource /ajax.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The error occurs only for some comments. I get this error while I was testing in live server whether the comment system works or not and checking TTFB in chrome developer tools. In my local server with xampp everything works fine and nice.

Now it's time to say the weirdest thing. The error occurs for comment "sdfgsdfg"; I was just randomly making comments to test and I get the error for this comment.

And I get the same error for another similar comment "sdfkjlkjlsdf". I can not test all comments in the world!

But works fine for comments like "fkjlkjf", "fghsdkjfdksfgh", etc. No one's going to add a comment like "sdfgsdfg" in my website but I need to fix this as well.

One more thing is I get the same error even when I go directly to the ajax page with some comments but for other comments everything works fine. Do not say that I didn't search online for this problem and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Do you know if Apache mod_security is installed on the server?

Comment: How do I check this anyway? I'm in shared hosting environment. But added this code <IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule> to disable it from other discussions. No luck!

Comment: This may help...  http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html

Comment: I already came through your link. Is there nothing to do to fix this myself?